# Here's a riddle, so listen up yo

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I'm from Italy, yet I speak English

On top of that, my name is French

I hail back from the late nineties galore

Last in 2016 did I release lore

Until then it has been a decade

But we never truly did fade

---

One of us is the key

One of us flies the wind

One of us controls sound

Together we are a force, world round

---

Back in my time, I was popular

Now the world I know seems not to know me not so much any more

Too much of heaven can bring you down

I know because it made me so blue

---

After the crash, we bloomed again

But we were not whole after that

Then the bloom went and we came again

But even as we still are that,

We still soon fell by one more

---

In addition, we have a "secret" member

Who's been with us since we began

We were once enemies, but now we're friends

Four times he has appeared

Three with us and one on his own

Can you find all four occurrences?

---

Can you guess who we are in whole, and name us each? Explain each line in whole, and we shall reward those who can figure us out.

In addition, name our friend, and say what four places he is to be found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are:

> The music group, Eiffel 65

*I'm from Italy, yet I speak English*

> The three members of the group are all Italian, yet they sing in English

*On top of that, my name is French*

> The group’s name hails from the Eiffel Tower in Paris

*I hail back from the late nineties galore*

> Their big breakthrough came in 1999 with their album *Europop*

*Last in 2016 did I release lore*

> *Panico/Critical* was released in Spring 2016

*Until then it has been a decade*
*But we never truly did fade*

> Prior to that they had not released anything since 2004.  However, in the meantime they continued to tour.

*One of us is the key*
*One of us flies the wind*
*One of us controls sound*
*Together we are a force, world round*

> Maurizio Lobina is a keyboardist, Jeffrey Jey is the vocalist and Gabry Ponte is a DJ, remixer and record producer. As an ensemble act they enjoyed international success.

*Back in my time, I was popular*
*Now the world I know seems not to know me not so much anymore*

> Eiffel 65 had great success as a pop act, hitting number 1 in many countries with their songs. However, these days they are arguably not as well known... These two lines also reference their songs *Back In Time* and *Johnny Grey* (lyric: 'the world I know seems not to know me') from their album *Contact!*

*Too much of heaven can bring you down*
*I know because it made me so blue*

> *Too Much of Heaven* is one of their singles, *Blue (Da Ba Dee)* is another

*After the crash, we bloomed again*
*But we not whole after that*

> After finishing recording their 4th album *Crash Test*, in 2005 Gabry Ponte left the group to embark on a solo career.  The remaining members continued to perform but under a new name: Bloom 06 (releasing the album under this name as *Crash Test 01*).

*Then the bloom went and we came again*

> After Bloom 06 the group reformed as Eiffel 65 in 2010

*But even as we still are that,*
*We still soon fell by one more*

> Ponte later re-left the group, in the sense that he no longer performs or records with them (although he is still listed as an official member, I believe).

*In addition, we have a "secret" member*
*Who's been with us since we began*
*We were once enemies, but now we're friends*
*Four times he has appeared*
*Three with us and one on his own*
*Can you find all four occurrences?*

> This refers to ‘Zorotl’, a blue alien character who features in the videos for *Blue (Da Ba Dee)*, *Move Your Body* and *Lucky (In My Life)*.  He was originally intended to be an adversary but when he was animated he looked too endearing and the music video for *Blue (Da Ba Dee)* instead gave him a happy ending, singing on-stage with the group. Zorotl proved so popular he in effect became a virtual band (akin to Gorillaz) and had his own single *I Wanna Be*.

As for the title itself:

> *Blue (Da Ba Dee)* begins with the line 'Yo listen up, here's the story...'

Comment: Ah yes! Edit to follow...

Comment: Also, what in particular gave you the answer?

Comment: I recognised the references to rot13('Gbb Zhpu bs Urnira' naq 'Oyhr' - V obhtug gung fvatyr!)